# What is difference between setText() and setContent() in BodyMimePart class

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, mime-types, gmail-api

What is the difference between these two functions as they provide the same result in JavaMail API?

```
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
BodyPart textBody = new MimeBodyPart();
textBody.setText(bodyText);
textBody.setContent(bodyText, "text/html") ;
multipart.addBodyPart(textBody);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose if you want to send a plane text then use `setText()` method. If you want to send the content of the `html` code, then you can go for `setContent()`.

Keep One point that, `setText()` and `setContent()` will override each other. Just use the `setText()` method that allows you to specify the charset and text type.

**For Ex :**

The below line send plain text

```
plainTextPart.setText("This is plain text message", "UTF-8");
```

and this one will send `html content`

```
htmlTextPart.setContent("<h1>This is plain HTML message</h1>", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

the text message will display in the header `<h1>` size.

Answer (score 3):

`setText(....)` is like `setContent(..., "text/plain")` where as `setContent(..., ...)` gives you more control over what MIME type you want to use.

So, in your example `textBody.setContent(bodyText, "text/html");` will override the previous call `textBody.setText(bodyText);` and change the content's MIME type from `text/plain` to `text/html`.

Comment: setContent is the more general method.  setText is customized for text content.  There's even a [version that allows you to specify the subtype](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) so you can use it for html content as well.